# How do I use WTL in a DLL?

Tags: dll, atl, bho, wtl

I'm trying to use WTL within an in-process COM server DLL (an IE BHO), but am struggling with _Module.

My DLL needs `CMyModule` derived from `CAtlDllModuleT<>`:

```
class CMyModule : public CAtlDllModuleT< CMyModule >
{
public:
    DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_MyLib)
    DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYPROJ, "{...}")
};

CMyModule _Module;

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(...)
{
    hInstance;
    return _Module.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved); 
}

...

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void)
{
    return _Module.DllUnregisterServer();
}
```

But this conflicts with most WTL examples, which require something like this within `stdafx.h`:

```
extern CAppModule _Module; // WTL version of CComModule
```

No matter which way I do it, I (unsurprisingly) get compile errors. `CMyModule` derived from `CAppModule` borks on `_Module.DllUnregisterServer()`, etc. `CMyModule` derived from `CAtlDllModuleT<>` borks on code like `_Module.GetMessageLoop()`.

Any good references on how WTL is supposed to work within a DLL? Google finds lots of questions, with few answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project that uses WTL in a DLL.  I looked at how my headers are set up and it looks like I hacked around this same problem...

I have my module set up like your sample code inheriting from CAtlDllModuleT<> except the name of the global module variable is _AtlModule rather than _Module.  For example:

```
class CMyModule : public CAtlDllModuleT< CMyModule >
{
public:
    DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_MyLib)
    DECLARE_REGISTRY_APPID_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYPROJ, "{...}")
};

CMyModule _AtlModule;
```

So, all of the DllMain.cpp entry points use _AtlModule. Then in the stdafx.h file it looks like this:

```
// WTL includes
#define _Module (*_pModule)
#include <atlapp.h>
#include <atlctrls.h>
#include <atldlgs.h>
#undef _Module
```

That _pModule thing is defined in atlbase.h like:

```
__declspec(selectany) CComModule* _pModule = NULL;
```

There must be a better way, but this does work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the option of multiple inheritance? Try inheriting from both CAtlDllModule and CAppModule since you need both.

Comment: I'd tried that but have given it a bit more of a go now. Gets me so far, but one things leads to another. Seems that multiple inheriting with CAtlBaseModule gives me too little (e.g. GetMessageLoop missing from _Module). Inheriting with CAppModule gives too much (e.g. ambiguous access of DLLMain).

Answer (score 0):

I use WTL in an Office add-in; the following works for me. (At the bottom of stdafx.h)

```
class DECLSPEC_UUID("XXXX-...") MyLib;

using namespace ATL;

/*
 * Application module
 */
class CAddInModule : public CAtlDllModuleT< CAddInModule >
{
public:
    CAddInModule() : m_hInstance(NULL)
    {
    }

    DECLARE_LIBID(__uuidof(MyLib))

    HINSTANCE GetResourceInstance()
    {
        return m_hInstance;
    }
    void SetResourceInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance)
    {
        m_hInstance = hInstance;
    }

private:

    HINSTANCE m_hInstance;
};

extern CAddInModule _AtlModule;
```

And then the DLL main use `_AtlModule`:

```
// DLL Entry Point
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    _AtlModule.SetResourceInstance(hInstance);
    return _AtlModule.DllMain(dwReason, lpReserved); 
}


// Used to determine whether the DLL can be unloaded by OLE
STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow(void)
{
    return _AtlModule.DllCanUnloadNow();
}


// Returns a class factory to create an object of the requested type
STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppv)
{
    return _AtlModule.DllGetClassObject(rclsid, riid, ppv);
}


// DllRegisterServer - Adds entries to the system registry
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    // registers object, typelib and all interfaces in typelib
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllRegisterServer();
    return hr;
}


// DllUnregisterServer - Removes entries from the system registry
STDAPI DllUnregisterServer(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = _AtlModule.DllUnregisterServer();
    return hr;
}
```